# Are scala reflection API Names or Symbols adequate for use inside transfer objects?

Tags: scala, reflection, dto, data-transfer-objects

## Introduction

I am working on an API written in Scala. I use data transfer objects (DTOs) as parameters passed to the API's functions. The DTOs will be instanciated by the API's user.

As the API is pretty abstract / generic I want to specify the attributes of a object that the API should operate on. Example:

```
case class Person(name: String, birthdate: Date)
```

When an instance of `Person` "P" is passed to the API, the API needs to know the attributes of "P" it should operate on: either just `name` or `birthdate`, or both of them.

So I need to design a DTO that contains the instance of "P" itself, some kind of declaration of the attributes and maybe additional information on the type of "P".

## String based approach

One way would be to use `String`s to specify the attributes of "P" and maybe its type. This would be relatively simple, as `String`s are pretty lightweight and well known. As there is a formal notation of packages, types and members as `String`s, the declarations would structured to a certain degree. 
On the other side, the `String`-declarations must be validated, because a user might pass invalid `String`s. I could imagine types that represent the attributes with dedicated types instead of `String`, which may have the benefit of increased structure and maybe even those type are designed so that only valid instances can exist.

## Reflection API approach

Of course the reflection API came to my mind and I am experimenting to declare the attributes with types out of the reflection API. Unfortunately the scala 2.10.x reflection API is a bit unintuitive. There are names, symbols, mirrors, types, typetags which can cause a bit of confusion.

Basically I see two alternatives to attribute declaration with `String`s:

1. Attribute declaration with reflection API's "Names"
2. Attribute declaration with reflection API's "Symbols" (especially TermSymbol)

If I go this way, as far as I can see, the API's user, who constructs the DTOs, will have to deal with the reflection API and its Names / Symbols. Also the API's implementation will have to make use of the reflection API. So there are two places with reflective code and the user must have at least a little bit of knowledge of the reflection API.

## Questions

However I don't know how heavyweight these approaches are:

- Are Names or Symbols expensive to construct?
- Does the reflection API do any caching of expensive operation results or should I take care about that?
- Are Names and Symbols transferable to another JVM via network?
- Are they serializable?

Main question: **Are scala reflection API Names or Symbols adequate for use inside transfer objects?**

It seems complicated to do this with the reflection API. Any hints are welcome. And any hints on other alternatives, too.

P.S.: I did not include my own code, yet, because my API is complex and the reflection part is in pretty experimental state. Maye I can deliver something useful later.

Answer (score 1):

1a) Names are easy to construct and are lightweight, as they are just a bit more than strings.

1b) Symbols can't be constructed by the user, but are created internally when one resolves names using APIs like `staticClass` or `member`. First calls to such APIs usually involve unpacking type signatures of symbol's owners from `ScalaSignature` annotations, so they might be costly. Subsequent calls use already loaded signatures, but still pay the cost of a by-name lookup in a sort of a hashtable [(1)](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/e20f9e9f1fcf2a25603b2b75528e4d9395557411/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Scopes.scala#L234). `declaration` costs less than `member`, because `declaration` doesn't look into base classes.

2) Type signatures (e.g. lists of members of classes, params + return type of methods, etc) are loaded lazily and therefore are cached. Mappings between Java and Scala reflection artifacts are cached as well [(2)](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/e20f9e9f1fcf2a25603b2b75528e4d9395557411/src/reflect/scala/reflect/runtime/JavaMirrors.scala#L94). To the best of my knowledge, the rest (e.g. subtyping checks) is generally uncached with a few minor exceptions.

3-4) Reflection artifacts depend on their universe and at the moment can't be serialized [(3)](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5919?filter=10908).

Comment: Thx for answering. Does Names give me any advantage over plain Strings?

Comment: Names are cached + names provide a tag that distinguishes terms and types. upd. I mean, newTermName("C") is different from newTypeName("C") even though the underlying strings are equal.